# Vue select change event firing before I trigger any action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli, vee-validate

I have a Vue app that seems to fire the change event even before I change the selection, recently tried the @input instead but still the same thing happens(as shown below)

**Please note I have tried @change and @input and the event still fires on loading of the controls**

Now this was working before I made css changes to scope the component, so that it doesn't effect the surrounding css. But cant fathom why this would make any difference.

Does anyone know why when adding the options tag and contents would make the change event fire?

```
<div class="form-group" :class="{formError: errors.has('formSection')}">
    <label for="formSection">Section*</label>
    {{ formModel }}
    <select
        v-model="formModel.idSection1"
        class="form-control"
        id="formSection"
        name="formSection"
        @input="onChangeSectionLevel1">
        <option v-for="sectionLevel1 in formModel.sectionLevel1" 
                                    v-bind:value="sectionLevel1.value" 
                                    v-bind:key="sectionLevel1.id">
                                    {{ sectionLevel1.value }}
        </option>
    </select>                                
    <span v-if="errors.has('formSection')">This field is required</span>
</div>
```

As soon as I add in the options tag which loops through the items the onChangeSectionLevel1 function gets called. I thought it might be vee-validate but taken this out and still happens.

```
methods: {
   onChangeSectionLevel1() {
      alert("changed");
      ...
   }
}
```

Update:

I have noticed that if I print out the object that is being bound, I get this which missing the **idSection1** item.

```
{
    "idSection2": null,
    "idSection3": null,
}
```

If I then just put a dummy option as below then I can see my 3 data items including the idSection1 that is missing if I loop through with the v-for

```
<select
    v-model="formModel.idSection1"
    class="form-control"
    id="formSection"
    name="formSection"
    @change="onChangeSectionLevel1">
    <option>Hello World</option>
</select>
```

The data item still has the idSection1 listed

```
{
    "idSection1": null,
    "idSection2": null,
    "idSection3": null
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you use `@change` instead of `@input`?

Comment: The same thing it still gets called

Comment: Are you updating `formModel.idSection1` value anywhere in js code?

Comment: Not as far as I can see, done a full search of the code base, update the question and added more detail as that might help! thanks

Comment: I am not sure what's happening on your end. Maybe you can try to create a simple demo for this using a simple select and options with v-for which comes from a small hardcoded array on jsFiddle or codesandbox and see if you can recreate the issue. If you can recreate the issue with simple demo also, then post it here so that others also can take a look into this.

Comment: You are correct it works find in jsfiddle. My only excuse its that this is not my code! lol. I believe I have found that the model is being fully replaced by an ajax call. I put breakpoints all over to see what was hit.So nothing wrong with the above code just people not using vue correctly I presume. cheers for the assist

Comment: It is very difficult to find a solution to an issue which can't be reproduced. As the js fiddle is working fine, it seems basically there some other issue in your end, which might be a complex codebase with multiple users modifying the code. I am sorry but I couldn't help much from here. You have to ask your colleagues or senior devs to see if they can spot anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but the code above is find and works as expected in js fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/andrewp37/a4obkhd5/1/

Code:

```
<div id="app">
  <label for="formSection">Section*</label>
  {{ formModel }}
  <select
          v-model="formModel.idSection1"
          class="form-control"
          id="formSection"
          name="formSection"
          @change="onChangeSectionLevel1">
    <option v-for="sectionLevel1 in formModel.sectionLevel1" 
            v-bind:value="sectionLevel1.value" 
            v-bind:key="sectionLevel1.id">
      {{ sectionLevel1.value }}
    </option>
  </select>  
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    formModel: {
        idSection1: null, 
      sectionLevel1: [
        {
                    id: 1, 
          value: "Section 1"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChangeSectionLevel1() {
     alert("changed");
    }
  }
})
```

I had noticed that with lots of breakpoints added, the model was being replaces after the page was mounted.